# subprocess Popen.process.stdout.readline hangs randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.7

I am trying to start a 3rd party program from python and send messages to it, reading the answer. I do not want to restart the 3rd party program after every message.

So what I have simplifies to this code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([executable, "-b", paramValue], 
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, bufsize=1)
# clear some startup message, which for some reason is written into stderr
process.stderr.readline()

while 100k+ loops:
    process.stdin.write(txtInputLine)
    resultLine = process.stdout.readline().strip()
    processData(txtInputLine, resultLine)
```

After some random amount of time, often around 30 minutes after the loop has started the program hangs and stops working. It appears readline() just hands and stops working entirely.

How can I prevent this? I would be fine with having to restart the process (maybe using some kind of timeout?) if it fails or something like that.

But I cannot even find where readline() is documented, it seems it is just mentioned in the subprocess docs, without a full documentation on the function and google has a hard time avoiding threads of people who have problems with missing newlines and other problems that prevent readline from working in a much more deterministic manner.

Comment: you're flooding your pc's memmory... lol. and you should create a working example. And think about if your script should have daemon activities.. what happens when you break from the while-loop? Just a `print('Done')` or something sufices in the wroking example. For workers.. use `def A(): dosomething`, etc.

Comment: .. in addition... you should code this from the  threading() or multiprocessing modules. The latter is for standalone applications and the threading is done under python GIL.

Comment: I am not running out of memory at all and need no threading, all I do is interface with a command line tool that does some computations that I need, specifically the subprocess is a c++ connect 4 solver, from which I need some positions solved.

Comment: ... my guess is that your return message around 30 minutes might have not utf8 chars or other unreadable code for python to interpreted or is parsing its ..first result to python and/or is too large in size... ?  Goodluck with pythons GIL and reading/parsing and processing messages all at once... without threading ;-)

Comment: The threading module is made for idle time between processes.. Use an editor for your tracebacks... GL.

Comment: Doc for readline is here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline

Comment: Have you hit some kind of buffer limit? E.g. you have given the program too much input and not reading enough from the output (or vice versa). Have you checked that the STDERR is not full of junks waiting to be cleared out? See if it works better if you don't send STDERR to PIPE?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some outputs on stderr that were never read and ended up blocking everything. Setting stderr to write to devnull solved the issue.